# PHP Image Upload - Locked Photos - FTP Error

Tags: php, html, image, ftp

I've been creating a website in the same way that I usually so, where I add an article + image using HTML & PHP. The difference is that when I upload the photo, even though it displays on the web page, my folder shows an Icon instead of the image (See Below):

[image]

As the photos show on the webpage I didn't think much of it, until I tried to upload the website, where I kept getting an FTP upload error on the images. Then when loading the website, I found that none of the images were there.

I'm not sure what the problem is, but when I tried to open one of the photos in Fireworks it says, "Could not open the file. File is locked".

Does anyone know what the probelm is? I'm using the same upload method used previously.

Comment: unlock the images by right-clicking and choosing 'unlock' (in your site folder - there's probably an icon with a lock beside the images)